# Why my QWebEngineView stucks at instagram loading screen and don't accept inputs like reload

Tags: python, pyqt, qwebengineview, qwebenginepage, qwebengine

When I run everything works fine except it stops at instagram splash/loading screen, even the right click menu option don't work. Works for PyQt5 but not from PyQt6.There is no problem with internet connection.

```py
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEnginePage, QWebEngineProfile
from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl


class Main(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.profile = QWebEngineProfile("data", self) # Create a off-road profile with parent self
        self.profile.setPersistentCookiesPolicy
        (QWebEngineProfile.PersistentCookiesPolicy.AllowPersistentCookies) # Force the cookie to be stored in disk
        self.profile.setHttpCacheType(QWebEngineProfile.HttpCacheType.DiskHttpCache) # Cache is stored in disk
        self.profile.setPersistentStoragePath('data') # Cookie path in data folder in root
        self.profile.setCachePath('data') # Cache path in data folder in root

        self.page = QWebEnginePage(self.profile) # Create a page with profile from above
        self.setPage(self.page) # not set page to QWebEngineView
        self.load(QUrl("https://www.instagram.com")) # load the url in view
        self.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main = Main()
app.exec()
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgdKv.png)

I tried opening google I guess only sign in button worked. In PyQt5 everything work except a little bit JS.
I expect the site to get load and it take input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug of QtWebEngine.(What about reporting this on [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-114695?jql=project%20%3D%20QTBUG)?) You can remedy the problem by using absolute paths like this.

```
import os
...
class Main(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.profile.setPersistentStoragePath(os.path.abspath('data'))
        self.profile.setCachePath(os.path.abspath('data'))
        ...
```